# Are major station services counter like Place de Clichy open till late evening to buy Navigo pass?

Tags: tickets, paris, night-transport, opening-hours, ratp

What are the work hours to buy Navigo Easy pass?

Are major station services counter like Place de Clichy open till late evening to buy Navigo Pass?

Comment: Good question. You can find sales points (you can get the pass from many shops) using [this map](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/cartes/points-de-vente), but they don't have opening times. (For shops you can try looking them up on Google Maps.) You can get the pass from some machines but I don't know if the RATP ones all have it. At least at [gare Saint-Lazare](https://www.garesetconnexions.sncf/fr/gares-services/paris-saint-lazare/services-commerces/accueil-transilien-ile-france) (~1km away) I'm sure you can get a pass until 1am.

Comment: I **think** that all metro stations are supposed to have a manned sales desk during their whole opening times, but I can't find any confirmation of that, and I haven't had the need for one at late hours in ages. Note however that some metro stations have multiple entrances, and then there's only one which will be maned all the time (or at all). Note also that in some cases personnel may have to temporarily step out of the sales desk for some operation in the station.

Comment: There are also shops selling Navigo passes. In the specific case of Place de Clichy, the "tabac" La Havane is open from 5am to 2am. Finally, if you have an Android phone, you don't need a pass at all, you can use your phone for that instead (supposedly coming to iOS early 2024).

Answer (score 2):

Most stations are staffed during all hours of service. (Note that not all entrances connect to the staffed office.)

You should be able to find the hours for a particular station, as there are some exceptions, from [this page](https://www.transilien.com/en/page-tarifs/navigo-services-counters).

Comment: The page you link to has a link to a page about ticket sales for Transilien (suburban trains) and RATP (metro). Only Transilien lists opening times, RATP doesn't. Metro stations used to be staffed at all hours of service, but that stopped a few years ago.